# hide smtp credentials from developers

Tags: authentication, smtp, phpmailer

We are bringing on a new temporary developer to help out with a project and I've been asked about installing libraries to store the SMTP login credentials to our dontreply@xyz.com email so that the developer can set up web forms without access to the credentials as this would require us to change the credentials for all out forms after the developer finishes her contract.

I've searched and found nothing, the closest thing was someone stating that you should create a company account instead of using personal account on this post: [PHPMailer Hide SMTP Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017622/phpmailer-hide-smtp-authentication)

can anyone help with me with this or point me in the right direction at least?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like that question says, there's not much you can do to prevent the dev getting hold of the credentials. Even OAuth won't help. This isn't a PHPMailer question, or even a PHP question really - it's about configuration management, and the same problems occur in pretty much all languages.

It may be solveable at a different level though - One option might be to wall off direct access using a mail proxy / relay. Configure a nearby/local mail server that you can submit to freely, and have that deal with real outbound, including relaying through your mail account. That way the developer can send through your chosen server without needing any direct access at all. It might make their life a little more difficult, but it solves your main problem.